MOUSEINPUT reset the mouse cursor on Windows
How to reset the mouse cursor to its default state (no button is clicked) without changing the position?
According to the MOUSEINPUT API, there is no "reset" function or "MOUSEEVENTF_RESET" event that can be passed to the SendInput function.
Currently, I'm keeping the state of each button (left clicked, right clicked, wheel clicked) and undoing the click with the corresponding mouse event to set the mouse to its normal state.

There is no "reset" state. If you are already tracking the state, you'll just have to send the reverse of your current state. IOW, if you think the current state is mousedown, then send a sole mouseup event. That is all you can do.
